# Question on divergent improper integrals

Tags: calculus, functions, improper-integrals

> If $\;f\;:[M,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R\;$ is a non-negative
>   $\;L_{loc}^1\;$function such that $\;\int_{M}^{\infty} f(s) \;ds
>  =+\infty\;$ for $\;M \gt 0\;$, *under which circumstances* is it true to claim that $\;\int_{M}^{N} f(s) \;ds \lt +\infty\;$ for $\;N \gt M
>  \gt 0\;$?

Although the above question seems intuitively always right, the following example came to my mind:

$\; \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{x} \;dx=+\infty=\int_{0}^{1} \frac {1}{x} \;dx\;$

Is this a counterexample for the initial question or $\;f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\;$ doesn't satisfy the above assumptions since $\;\frac{1}{x}\;$ is defined on $\; (0,+\infty) \;$ and not on $\; [0,+\infty) \;$?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For *some* $N$ or *all* $N$?

Comment: $M$ is strictly positive; I don't see how the example $\int_{[0,\infty]}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ is related.

Comment: @Jack I suppose for all $\;N\;\lt \infty\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that $f$ is not defined at $0$ - we could define it arbitrarily there - it is that $f\colon x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ isn't locally integrable at $0$, however we define it at $0$:

$$\int_0^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{x}\,dx = +\infty$$

for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

The hypothesis is that we have a locally integrable function, and that implies that the function is integrable over all compact subsets of $[M,+\infty)$. Since $[M,N]$ is compact for all $M < N < +\infty$, the local integrability of $f$ guarantees

$$\int_M^N f(s)\,ds < +\infty$$

for all $M < N < +\infty$.

Comment: ♦ Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!